# Redis not completing search when it ends in a colon(:)

Tags: php, redis

I am trying to do an autocomplete search on a sorted set.  It will not actually complete the search when the input ends in a colon like $input = "00:".  I can use double quotes and surround the input and it works but searches go from 2ms to 15 seconds.

```
 $input = "00:2" works in 2ms
 $input = "00:" doesnt work
 $input = '"00:"'; works in 15 seconds


 function getNextChar($char) {
     $char++;
     if(strlen($char) > 1) { $char--; }
     return $char;
 }

 function getLexicalAutocomplete($redis, $dictionaryKey, $input) {
     $inputNext = substr($input, 0, -1) . getNextChar(substr($input, -1)); //ab -> ac

     $redis->zadd($dictionaryKey, 0, $input);
     $redis->zadd($dictionaryKey, 0, $inputNext);

     $rangeStart = $redis->zrank($dictionaryKey, $input)+1;
     $rangeEnd = $redis->zrank($dictionaryKey, $inputNext)-1;

     $autocompleteResults = $redis->zrange($dictionaryKey, $rangeStart, $rangeEnd);

     $redis->zrem($dictionaryKey, $input);
     $redis->zrem($dictionaryKey, $inputNext);

     return $autocompleteResults;
 }
```

Comment: a) you don't need to add and then remove your "range" keys - just do the zrange. b) zrange is usually used for score searching whereas zrangebylex is usually employed for lexical order c) what does your SLOWLOG say?

Comment: I was using an old version of Redis 2.4ish